# How to take out list of elements from string?

Tags: c, string

I have a parser that detects strings between specific tags such as `<"title">Example<"/title">`. But some of the tags have codes in xml such as `&ltg#;`

Is there any C function that can detect a list of tags and replace or take those parts out?

Comment: not a single function, but you can have a look at the functions in `string.h`. Lot of functions are there which, when used together, can get this done.

Comment: If possible, I recommend `Python`, `Perl` or something similar for this purpose.

Comment: Maybe construct a parser that detects `&ltg#;`, too?

Comment: Detection might be as simple as using `strstr()`; replacement requires more care - doubly so if the replacement text is longer than what it replaces.  However, if you have many tags to match, you want a more intelligent parser than `strstr()`.

Comment: If I use the strstr(); function, how would I be able to eliminate the substring when it returns only the position?